# angular2 No provider for Http in Angular v4

Tags: angular

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
```

When I use `http` I get a error that "No provider for Http",

then I import `HTTP_PROVIDERS` but HTTP_PROVIDERS has no exported member

Comment: Read the documentation and follow the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/b307j9A0cpdFj2cLvem0?p=preview) on inserting http. Read more about [http module](https://angular.io/guide/http)

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule ],
 declarations: [ App ],
 bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Sorry It's not work

Comment: :-) thats why i created plunker. to show it works. anyway to use it you should write   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

Comment: Cause old client will be deprecated.

Comment: like this ? import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"; 
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log(this.http);
  }

It is still not work with error "No provider for HttpClient"

Comment: Have You done this line  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule ],

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_PROVIDERS was deprecated in current version.
But which verions of angular cli, angular compiler, and angular core do you use?
  in latest version, you have to use this:

```js
/* in app.module.ts */
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
  ....
}
```

Comment: @angular/cli: 1.3.2
node: 6.11.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.6
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
Here is my angular version 
just only import HttpModule It is not work

Comment: Hi toney, as I commented, you have to use HttpModule, and then import that to @NgModule.